# Get return value from a Backbone event listener callback function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a function (`getHealth`) in one js file `LoadSolutionView` to return a percentage.

In another JS file as an entry point on page load where I have an event listener for this function as follows

```
function getHealth(dow) {
        Main.Views.LoadSolutionView.getHealth(dow);
}
Main.EventAggregator.listenTo(Main.Views.OverviewView, 'getHealth', getHealth);
```

In my `OverviewView` file, I have the following function that triggers the `getHealth` function successfully but I do not get the returned value, instead I get all childs of `this`. Is there a means of getting the returned value from triggering the `getHealth` function?

```
saveRooms: function(dayId, solutionId, shiftId, day) {
    var self = this;

    var roomIds = self.getIds('roomsEdit');
    roomIds = _.map(roomIds, Number);

    this.trigger('editShiftDay', this.solution, this.dto, this.numDays, this.endDate, solutionId, dayId, day);

    var percentage = this.trigger('getHealth', dayId);

    this.hideOptions();

    this.checkForChanges();
},
```

Comment: Why assign `self` as `this` if you only use `this` ? Isn't `$(this)` ??

Comment: It's a force of habit if I ever use loops I need to use self. Using `$(this)` do not trigger the function so I believe I am correct in using `this`

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking about `$(this)`, sorry.

Comment: Most Underscore function offers an optional `context` argument. I personally never use `var self = this;` technique in my Backbone apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Backbone Events `trigger` function returns `this` for chaining purpose.

An event is not like a function call. Keep in mind that no code could be listening to it, or that multiple listeners could be bound to that event, so a return value would make no sense.

It's good to use events to avoid strong coupling. If the view triggering the event needs some data back, there are some patterns you can use.

## Pass a callback with the event

```
onHealthCallback: function(health) {
    /* use health here */
},

saveRooms: function(dayId, solutionId, shiftId, day) {
    /* ... */
    this.trigger('getHealth', dayId, this.onHealthCallback.bind(this));
    /* ... */
},
```

Using Function's `bind` method, `this` will be available in `onHealthCallback`.

Then, the listener can just call the callback passing the arguments you're expecting.

```
this.listenTo(OverviewView, 'getHealth', function(dayId, callback) {
    callback(LoadSolutionView.getHealth(dayId));
});
```

## Pass the view

```
setHealth: function(health) {
    this.health = health;
    this.reactToHealhChange();
},

saveRooms: function(dayId, solutionId, shiftId, day) {
    /* ... */
    this.trigger('getHealth', dayId, this);
    /* ... */
},
```

`bind` is unnecessary since we're passing the whole instance.

The listener has now access to the complete view, more flexible but more exposed.

```
this.listenTo(OverviewView, 'getHealth', function(dayId, view) {
    view.setHealth(LoadSolutionView.getHealth(dayId));
});
```